# Hover over input label not working

Tags: html, css, hover

**http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/6vwLetd6/13/**

I have a custom sign up form with styles from a [Codrops demo page](http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/).

Basically on hover I want to animate the label text (have it fade in and out) but for now just trying to get the text to change color to red:

```css
.input__label-content--jiro:hover {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<span id="full_name_label" class="input input_jiro">
  <input class="input__field input__field--jiro" type="text" id="input-1" />
  <label class="input__label input__label--jiro" for="input-1">
    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--jiro">
      Full Name
    </span>
  </label>
</span>
```

However when you hover over "Full Name" the color doesn't change. Can you see what is blocking the `hover` effect?

Comment: The edit works fine for me too... The JSFiddle however does not.

Comment: For me too [minlength]

Comment: Yeah it was the fiddle, I figured it out... `.input__label--jiro` had `pointer-events: none;` on it, that's why. Now just got to get my animation working :)

Comment: @LeonGaban You should probably just close this question then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've removed `pointer-events: none` declaration and it works.

Take a look at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vwLetd6/14/).

So I think You only need to overwrite this one according to `auto` value => [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Is this what You want??